# Block CMP banner for Googlebot

Tags: googlebot

I would like to exclude a Cookie Consent Banner (CMP Banner) for the Googlebot. My approach: The Googlebot should not see the banner at all. If Googlebot appears in the user agent, the script should not be loaded into the page via the Tag Manager. How can I implement this best?